# posting from Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, postman

I have built a JWT Authentication API that contains user data. When testing with POSTman the server will return the data, when posting via Axios my API receives the request but returns a null value.

POSTMAN:

```
Headers:
- Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Body:
- email: 'testuser1@company.com'
- password: 'String'
```

Axios - [View full code here](https://pastebin.com/7pVr8pY9)

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost:8081/api/authenticate', {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }, {
                    headers: { 
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                })
```

Comment: check that the email is not breaking the request because of the `@` symbol.

Comment: @GabMic it doesn't in the POSTMAN POST is there a reason why it would in an Axios. Also how do i check if it does break the Axios request?

Comment: you check if it breaks when you check if it reaches the backend properly. Is it laravel in the backend?

Comment: @GabMic It's ExpressJS. req.body.email is how my API gets the email address. it works when posted from POSTMAN but when posted from Axios it is `undefined`

Comment: Did you made a request to another server?

Comment: @GabMic Confirmed not a CORS problem

Comment: Can you generate code from Postman in AJAX (JavaScript) format - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/  and then just fill in the data in axios request and then try hitting the URL. It might be possible that you're missing onto some properties?

Comment: @SivcanSingh I've tried that as you've mentioned however it didn't work.

Comment: If you try this in Chrome you can see in DevTools how exactly the HTTP request body looks like. Or you can even use Fiddler to capture the raw bytes.